# Grails searchable: search for a specific field in a member object?

Tags: plugins, grails, searchable

Using the Grails Searchable plugin, I've got these classes:

```
class Person {
 static searchable = {
  address component: true
    }
}
```

and:

```
class Address {
 static searchable = {
  root false
 }
 String country
}
```

I want to do a specific search for persons from a specific country. "country:NL" doesn't work. "address:country:NL" doesn't work either. I can't find anything about the syntax for this. Any ideas?

I think I'll have to do some clever indexing or some other trick in the searchable closure, but I just can't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a basic app (Grails 1.3.5, Searchable 0.5.5.1) with your two classes and searching for 'country:NL' works for me. Did you remember to call index() before trying to search?

```
grails create-app search
grains install-plugin searchable
```

Person:

```
class Person {
  static searchable = {
    address component: true
  }

  Address address
}
```

Address:

```
class Address {
  static belongsTo = Person
  static searchable = {
    root false
  }
  String country
}
```

Bootstrap:

```
class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->

      def p1 = new Person(address:new Address(country:'NL')).save()
      def p2 = new Person(address:new Address(country:'DE')).save()
      def p3 = new Person(address:new Address(country:'NZ')).save()

      Person.index()

    }

    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

Then I browsed to to /searchable and searched for country:NL and got person 1 returned.

If you want to see what Searchable is doing under the covers with regards to fields/indexes etc - Luke is a very handy tool (just download the executable JAR): http://code.google.com/p/luke/

The index files are in

```
<user.home>/.grails/projects/<project name>/searchable-index/development/index
```

cheers

Lee

Comment: Your example sounds exactly like how I expected it to work, but for me it doesn't. (Simpler searches do work, so that's not the issue.) I'll give Luke a try to see if it's being indexed at all. I guess it's good to know that this is actually supposed to work like I expected. Now to figure out why it doesn't work for my project.

Answer (score 0):

The ugly solution that works: don't rely on Searchable. At the moment I first do a `Person.search(params.query, [max:99999]).results`, then do simple .findAll to find by country and .sublist() to get paging to work again.

It's a shame it's so hard to get something so obvious to work with Searchable.

Another solution I haven't gotten to work is making country a transient property on Person that returns address.country. Didn't work out of the box, and I have no idea on how to fix it.

If anyone has any prettier solutions for me, I'd love to hear them.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to grails but why do you have to use the searchable plugin ?

what is wrong with a simple 1:1 or 1:n relationship ?

```
    package com.test
class Person {

        static constraints = {
          name (nullable:false)
          address (nullable:true)
        }

        String name
        Address address

        String toString() {
          "name[" + name + "]. address[" + address + "]"
        }

        static mapping = {
          address lazy:false
        }
    }


    class Address {

        static constraints = {
          country (nullable:false)
          town   (nullable:false)
        }
        String country
        String town
        //Person person

        static  belongsTo = [person:Person]
    //    static  belongsTo = Person

        String toString(){
          "town[" + town + "], country[" + country + "]"
        }
    }

        package com.test

        import grails.test.*

        class PersonIntegrationTestTests extends GrailsUnitTestCase {
            protected void setUp() {
                super.setUp()
            }

            protected void tearDown() {
                super.tearDown()
            }

            void testSomething() {
              def bill = new Person(name:'bill', address:new Address(town:'york', country:'UK')).save()
              def fred = new Person(name:'fred', address:new Address(town:'leeds', country:'UK')).save()
              def bjork = new Person(name:'helen', address:new Address(town:'helsinki', country:'finland')).save()
              def gustav = new Person(name:'john', address:new Address(town:'helsinki', country:'finland')).save()

              List ukAddresses = Address.findAllByCountry('UK') // find all by country

              println "num addresses-" + ukAddresses.size()

              for (int i in 0..<ukAddresses.size())
              {
                println "found person:" + ukAddresses[i].person
              }

              assertNotNull "bill can not ne null", bill
              assertTrue bill.validate() && !bill.hasErrors()
              assertTrue fred.validate() && !fred.hasErrors()
              assertTrue bjork.validate() && !bjork.hasErrors()
              assertTrue gustav.validate() && !gustav.hasErrors()

              assertEquals 2, ukAddresses.size()
            }
        }
```